# Layer 2 VPN over SSH without allowing remote root access

Tags: ssh, vpn

SSH added a new option (-w) to allow the creation of TUN/TAP tunnels. All available tutorials I've found so far http://ku1ik.com/2011/11/12/tunnel-vm-network-ssh.html requests allowing remote root login.

Is there a way to enable this type of tunneling without the need to allow remote root login ?

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial you linked:

> Because only privileged users can create network interfaces you need to run this command as root, ssh-ing to remote host as root user as well.

That sounds like a 'no' to me. If you have root access why not setup a proper vpn service (such as OpenVPN)?

Comment: What do you mean by setup a proper VPN service ? do you mean using VPN solutions like OpenVPN ?

Comment: Creating a site-to-site OpenVPN connection is easy. See http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html and http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html